# Threads in jMonkey and Nifty?

Tags: java, multithreading, jmonkeyengine

I have recently learnt that jMonkey operates on only a single thread which is its openGL render thread. However I'm not able to understand it completely. I can understand that it executes all update and initialize() calls on a single update loop but input should be independent of this update loop, otherwise it will become a polling mechanism.

1. What exactly happens when the jMonkey application starts. Three tasks that it needs to do is run a update loop, run initialize methods of app states once, do rendering and constantly cater to events? How does it manage all of this via a single thread?
2. What happens when I add a new app state in the initialize method of another app state?
3. In input handling input manager notifies the various listeners about events. How are nifty callback events say onClick() are handled on the same render loop?
4. Lastly in which order this listen- update-render loop runs and where we can find code related to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jME uses an approach that's very common in a lot of game engines (and also used in some other user interface libraries such as Swing).

Everything that the game engine does is done in one thread. This can be called the LWJGL thread but as jME can work with alternatives to LWJGL it's more generic to call it the Render Thread or just the jME Thread.

Everything is indeed done on the Render thread, and it does indeed use a polling mechanism. For example if you are holding down the "left" key then each frame the relevant control or app state will be called on the render thread and will move you left by an amount modified by tpf. Tpf is time-per-frame and is very important for keeping smooth movement and letting game systems run at the same speed independently of frame rate.

The only thing within jME3 that commonly uses a separate thread is the Physics Engine. That has a thread that it uses for doing the physics updates and then changes are pushed through to the Render thread using appropriate mechanisms. The system handles this for you though so it is not something you need to worry about.

1. The thread runs around a game loop. Each time around the loop it checks for things it needs to do (like enqueued tasks, initialize app states, render, etc. It calls update in each active Controller and control, etc). Once it has finished updating everything it then goes on to perform the render. All of this happens every single frame, but computers are so fast that it can still handle all of that and render the game at good frame rates.
2. That's an implementation detail that you shouldn't need to worry about except to know that it will definitely work. The adding actually gets queued up and handled in the next frame I think.
3. Everything is handled from the same loop. jME calls through to Nifty to allow Nifty to do its processing. As part of that processing Nifty detects the events and fires off the callback. This means that the callbacks are already coming in on the render thread so you can safely modify the scene graph. jME uses some specially written collections such as SafeArrayList to allow you to modify the scene graph at the same time as iterating over it.
4. Update, Render, Update, Render, etc. Events firing generally happens as part of the update process when an update is detected. To find the code start by looking in the Application class, you should be able to find the main game loop in there by tracing through from the `start()` call.

The jME3 Threading Tutorial covers a fair amount of this:

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:multithreading

Comment: Thanks. I have understood most part(esp nifty interacting with jme) except one single thing. Inputs are captures as interrupts in OS. How exactly they flow their way as actions queuing up in jME. What are steps involved?

Comment: @simar That's handled by the input manager, I'm not familiar with the details, sorry.